# Flex layout - let the elements in the container in the same row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a question about flex, I can not make the sub-chart on the same row.

My current page:
Main chart
Sub Chart 1
Sub Chart 2
Sub Chart 3
Sub Chart 4
Sub Chart 5
Sub Chart 6
Sub Chart 7
Sub Chart 8

And this is what I want:
Main chart
Sub Chart 1 Sub Chart 2
Sub Chart 3 Sub Chart 4
Sub Chart 5 Sub Chart 6
Sub Chart 7 Sub Chart 8

here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/puff-vayne/pen/dyNRJJK)

HTML

```css
.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.main-chart {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #BDCCFF;
}

.row {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.sub-chart {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Flex 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-flex-1.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="dashboard">
    <div class="main-chart">Main chart</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="sub-chart even">Sub Chart 1</div>
        <div class="sub-chart odd">Sub Chart 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="sub-chart even">Sub Chart 3</div>
        <div class="sub-chart odd">Sub Chart 4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="sub-chart even">Sub Chart 5</div>
        <div class="sub-chart odd">Sub Chart 6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="sub-chart even">Sub Chart 7</div>
        <div class="sub-chart odd">Sub Chart 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `.row {
  flex: 1 100%;
}` to `.row { flex: 1 50%; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. It should be divided by the number of subchart you want. for e.g if you want 3, you set it to flex: 1 33.33%

```
.row {
    flex: 1 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change `flex: 1 50%;` in row class

```
.row {
    flex: 1 50%;
}
```